# Displaying users name on every page using sessions

Tags: php, forms, session

I am currently creating a website that will allow the user to log in using a username only, no password is required. Once the user has typed their name into the form, their name should then be placed on all of the pages they then visit until they log out.

The problem/s I am facing is that the username is not showing on the other pages once logged in. Instead I have been getting problems such as errors (*Notice: Undefined index: username in /ceri/homes1/s/sec17/public_html/cs25010/home.php on line 41*) and the nothing showing up at all.

Here is the code for the login page:

```
<?php
session_save_path("/aber/sec17/public_html/cs25010/tmp");
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
    header("Location: home.php");
}
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sean Coyne's Food Shop</title>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="description" content="Welcome to Sean Coyne's Food Shop" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Sean Coyne's Food Shop" 
            title="Sean Coyne's Food Shop" width="400px" height="70px"/>



        </div>

        <div id="nav">
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="database.php">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="drink.php.html">Offers</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="findus.php">Where to find us</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div id="main">
            <h1>Welcome to Sean Coyne's Food Shop</h1>
            <h2>Please Log In below:</h2>
            <br></br>
            <div id="login">
                <?php
                    echo '<form action="home.php" method"post"> 
                <input type="text" name="username" text="input username"
                placeholder="Username" required> 
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /> 
                </form>';
                ?>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here the code for the home page: (*I will not be placing the username here when its finished, this is just while im testing it to see if its working*)

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="description" content="Welcome to Sean Coyne's Food Shop" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Sean Coyne's Food Shop" 
            title="Sean Coyne's Food Shop" width="400px" height="70px"/>

        </div>

        <div id="nav">
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="database.php">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="drink.php.html">Offers</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="findus.php">Where to find us</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div id="main">
            <h1>Welcome to Sean Coyne's Food Shop</h1>

                <?php
                    echo $_SESSION['username'];
                ?>

        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Heres what it currently look like when you log in:

[image: Screenshot of the Home Page]

Comment: It looks like you question was answered, but just figured I would comment on this functionality, which seems weird.  Why would you require a person to enter their name if they are going to get absolutely nothing out of providing you that information, other than to have their name shown on other pages of the website during their current session only? It would seem like you are adding additional complexity in your system and a barrier for entry to the user without deriving any value whatsoever from it.

Comment: Basically their will be a temporary basket that users can place stuff in that has to be remembered throughout the time they are on the site.

Comment: @SeanCoyne But why they need to "login" to get this cart functionality? It's not like you are persisting the cart in a data store across sessions. If you need their name to ultimately check out, fine collect the name in the checkout process, but why impose a barrier to entry to even get the cart functionality?

Comment: This is part of an assignment, i totally know what you mean though but at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. Otherwise default method for form method is get.

Change:

```
<form action="home.php" method"post">
```

To this:

```
<form action="home.php" method="post">
```

Comment: Thanks, I am still getting the same error on the home page (Notice: Undefined index: username in /ceri/homes1/s/sec17/public_html/cs25010/home.php on line 41).